# Lumen/Laravel: Create models and relationships from database

Tags: laravel, lumen

I have a very large database, well over 350 tables. I'm trying to write an API to abstract database access, and I'm using Lumen to do this.

I've found a few tools that will create models based on the database, but they require manually entering the table name to work, this would be a hassle with 350 tables.

On top of that, I would like it to recognize and generate relationships within the Models. (i.e, when it comes accross `user_id` column in a table, it knows to associate that with the `id` column in the `users` table.

If this is unrealistic I can understand that, however if a tool exists that can do this I would be much appreciative.

I've seen some similar questions to this, however they all list outdated or dead options for achieving the result I want, and very few if any of them give an option for generating relationships on top of the Models.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/krlove/eloquent-model-generator? Regarding "manually entering the table name to work": Can't you just loop over all the tables and call the command for each one?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I've looked at that one, but as far as i can tell, it doesn't support relationships?

Comment: There are relationships in their example. Do you have foreign keys in your database?